# how to remove spaces and extra commas between commas and replace them by ' ' in csv by python

Tags: python, csv, data-analysis

This is my CSV:

```
AAP,AAMC,AAPL,AMT

106.08999633789062,,,

,122.88999938964844,,

,,109.80000305175781,

,,,118.55000305175781
```

here my second row is getting printed in staircase because of all the ',' and newline how do I get all the data in same row indent by using python?

I have tried using .replace function but it need hard coding every time.Is there a way I can find pattern so that :

so expected output is like:

```
AAP,AAMC,AAPL,AMT
106.08999633789062,122.88999938964844,109.80000305175781,118.55000305175781
```

Comment: your csv contains 4 rows that are mostly empty. You neither show code that creates nor processes it. Please share your efforts - we are no coding service.

Comment: If those values where supposed to be one single row then you'd rather fix the code that produces broken csv rather than trying to guess which part belong to which row.

Comment: @PatrickArtner  Apologies from me , I forgot to post the code , anyways I can tell you that this is an output of a data-frame downloaded by pandas_data-reader function which I used from python to get Stock values and I'm trying to concat multiple data-frames horizontally

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers  Apologies from me , I forgot to post the code , anyways I can tell you that this is an output of a data-frame downloaded by pandas_data-reader function which I used from python to get Stock values and I'm trying to concat multiple data-frames horizontally

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import csv
data = {}
with open('input.txt') as input_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(input_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        for key, value in row.items():
            if value:
                data[key] = value
with open('output.txt', 'w', newline='') as output_file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, delimiter=',', fieldnames=data.keys())
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow(data)
```

data is :

```
{'AAMC': '122.88999938964844',
 'AAP': '106.08999633789062',
 'AAPL': '109.80000305175781',
 'AMT': '118.55000305175781'}
```

Output.txt :

```
AAP,AAMC,AAPL,AMT
106.08999633789062,122.88999938964844,109.80000305175781,118.55000305175781
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this optimal solution , it seems to work in my case when I use DictReader .

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('a.csv')
m = df.max()
print(list(m.keys())); print(list(m.values))
# => ['AAP', 'AAMC', 'AAPL', 'AMT']
# => [106.08999633789062, 122.88999938964844, 109.8000030517578, 118.5500030517578]
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, it works fine if I want to print it on the shell , But how do I write the list into a csv since it is not callable ??

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below code :

```
import pandas as pd 
df=pd.read_csv("a.csv",delimeter=',',skipinitialspace=True,delim_whitespace=True)
print(list(df.keys()))
print(list(df.values()))
df.to_csv("b.csv",index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, it works fine if I want to print it on the shell , But how do I write the list into a csv since it is not callable ??